# Perl File::Find isn't running recursively

Tags: perl

I have this basic Perl script that should traverse my directory tree recursively.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use File::Find;
my $dir = '/mnt/drawings';

find(\&process_file, $dir);

sub process_file
{
    print("$File::Find::name\n");
}
```

But when I run it on my CentOS system it only prints the first level under '/mnt/drawings' around 20 directory. But when I run the same script on my FreeBSD system, it prints every file tens of thousands...

What am I missing on my CentOS system?

**Update:**

Both systems are mounting the same data on FreeNAS.
If I run `ls -lR` I can see all the files:
Here's the first few folders:

```
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   0 Mar 25  2011 2008dwgs
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   0 Nov 19  2015 2009dwgs
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   0 Oct 21  2016 2010dwgs
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   0 Jun 16  2014 2011dwgs
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   0 May 14 17:58 2012dwgs
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   0 Nov 29  2016 2013dwgs
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   0 Aug  8  2018 2014dwgs
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   0 Apr  1 18:11 2015dwgs
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   0 Jul 28 21:55 2016dwgs
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   0 Jun 17 12:39 2017dwgs
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   0 Jun 11 10:27 2018dwgs
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   0 Jul 26 15:40 2019dwgs
```

And here it is inside the 2008dwgs folder:

```
./2008dwgs:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 0 May 20  2014 08002-01
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 0 Apr  9  2011 08003
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 0 May 28  2013 08008
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 0 Nov 10  2014 08009
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 0 Jan 23  2008 08011
```

And inside the 08002-01 folder:

```
./2008dwgs/08002-01:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 0 May 20  2014 ArchDwgs
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 0 Aug 28  2014 BASES
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 0 May 20  2014 FinalPDF
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 0 Oct 13  2009 Fonts
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 0 Aug 27  2014 issued
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 0 May 19  2011 NPS Reference
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 0 Oct 13  2009 Pen Settings
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 0 Aug 27  2014 Received
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 0 Dec  8  2009 SketchUp
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 0 Jun 24 03:05 Struct
```

Comment: Is `/mnt/drawings` the same on both systems? Can you run with `ls -lR` and show us at least the first 10 lines?

Comment: @Schwern, I've added more info to the original post. Yes, I can see all the files with `ls -lR`

Comment: Is this a network file system? That might be confusing File::Find. Try using the latest version of Perl you can. What versions of Perl are you using on both machines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've found the bug. [Perlbug 133673](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=133673).

> I looked at the code in Find.pm and I see that it automatically avoids
>   using the number of links to a directory when `stat` on the directory
>   returns less than 2 for nlink. Unfortunately, it appears that directories on the NAS return 2 as the number of links for all directories.

That's what your network filesystem is doing.

[The fix](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/commit/f75dfdbdb9d52b3024db9a0eb27405c2175af144) is in Perl 5.30.0. You can upgrade, or you can set `local $File::Find::dont_use_nlink = 1;` to ignore the filesystem nlink.

Comment: Thanks @Schwern the `local $File::Find::dont_use_nlink = 1;` worked.